# Visiting multiple links on a page. [codeception]

Tags: php, tdd, bdd, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am a complete newbie with automatized testing software.
(Codeception and PHP7 are installed on a Centos 7 environment.)

**Conditions:**

1. My Index.html page includes x number of links
2. When (a href) links are visited, Page displays 'You have Selected Item i'.
3. Within the links, y number of faulty links may exist. When faulty links are visited, it displays an alert pop up saying the item selected does not exist.

**What I am trying to do:**
Build a test checking existence of faulty links. If exist, then returns the anchor text of the link.

**Here is what I did:  (obviously wrong..)**

```
<?php <br>
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);<br>
$I->wantTo('browse items');<br>
$I->amOnPage('/index.html');<br>
$I->click('a');<br>
$I->see('You have Selected Item i');<br>
```

**Problem**
Above code it enters the first link, then it checks the given text. 
After checking the first one, no matter with the result, I want it to check the next link on the index.html until all the links are visited. However it remains at the visited page and stops there.

**I hope it is clear enough. Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3):

So I got this answer, with the help from '@Alx101' and '@Naktibalda'.
Really Appreciated.

**Here I share my answer:**

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('browse items');
$I->amOnPage('/index.html');
$aLinks = $I->grabMultiple('a','href');

foreach($aLinks as $link) {
    $I->amOnPage('/'.$link);
    $I->see('Selected Item');
    $I->moveback();
    echo $link;
}
```

**Any answers shared with other or improved methods will be appreciated! :)**